# Performance between sending int or byte array over TCP in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, tcp, integer, client-server

I am implementing a clien-server streaming application with `H264` video file.

I use `BufferedInputStream` to read the `H264` file as following:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
int read = bis.read();
```

and use `DataOutputStream` to send the streaming data over TCP.

```
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

When I read streaming data from `BufferedInputStream:read()`, it returns `int`.

I am not sure if I should send streaming data as `int` or better first convert it into `byte[]` array and send `byte` array over TCP.

I choose TCP to secure the reliability (no video frame may be lost).

Between sending `int` and `byte[]` over TCP, which one gives a better performance? Put it in a simple way, which one will be sent and received faster?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `read()` method, which returns an int, it still only returns a byte worth of data. It's not like it receives a full 4-byte int which was sent. The reason why the return type is int even though it receives a byte is explained in the Javadoc. It's to signal the end-of-(stream/file/etc.) by returning `-1` instead of a (0-255) byte value. When you actually send an int (I don't know how you'd do that without a `DataOutputStream`), you'd receive 4 bytes.

About performance: As a rule of thumb, network is orders of magnitude slower than CPU, so there'll be no noticeable difference between byte-oriented or array-oriented methods (as long as both sides use a *buffered* strategy).

[edit] However, using arrays is what you'd expect in a case where you send BLOBs (Binary Large OBjects), so other programmers (and future you) will understand the code better if you use arrays.

Comment: Of course I use `DataOutputStream` to send the streaming data. So when I send an int (in the `read` variable from the code sample above) like this `DataOutputStream::write(read)` or `DataOutputStream::writeByte(read)`, the client still receives 4 bytes containing video frame?

Comment: No.  Both of those methods write a single byte.  So the client will only receive one byte.  Read the javadocs!    (If your code is incorrect 'cos you don't understand the standard APIs, it doesn't matter how fast it is.)

Comment: There is no 'of course' for `DataOutputStream`. It's an optional class meant solely for serializing the different Java primitives and UTF-8 strings (String is an oddball Java 'primitive'). When you only send byte streams (like video in your case) you won't normally use it.

Comment: And I glanced over your code and didn't notice you actually used `DataOutputStream`. Normally when you wrap a raw stream, you wrap it in `BufferedOutputStream` so my eye incorrectly thought it saw *that*.